# Render an asynchronous report, wider than the screen, without extra scrollbars

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, reportingservices-2005

I have an asynchronous local SSRS 2005 report that is of variable height and width, but routinely is bigger than the screen.  I want to render it full size so that some of the report renders off screen and the only scrollbars the user sees are the ones on the browser window.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

The only method that I've found that even comes remotely close to what I want is to set static width/height values that are much larger than the report will ever be. But, this is undesirable since it leaves so much extra whitespace in the browser window.

Has anyone had success rendering asynchronous reports without the extra scrollbars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only option would be to set SizeToReportContent option on the ReportViewer control. However in 2005 local mode with async enabled its ignored, however its fixed in the 2010 ReportViewer control (note, 2010 ReportViewer implements 2008 format but for local mode).

Another option would be to try to use some JavaScript to resize the ReportViewer control to the full browser height and also on resizing so there are only the ReportViewer scroll bars.

Comment: Are you saying the ReportViewer is fixed in 2010 only if my reports are not local?  If so, I really have to start storing my reports on a Reporting server!

Comment: No in 2005 WITHOUT async SizeToReportContent *should* work. In 2010 you can use both async AND SizeToReportContent.